# Define a linear operator on a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis

I am writing a prove in which I need to define a linear operator $T\in B(X)$ by

$$Tx=\lim_{n\to\infty}T_0x_n$$

where $T_0:S\rightarrow X$ is a bounded linear operator defined on a dense subset $S\subset X$ and $x_n$ is a sequence in $S$ such that $x_n\rightarrow x$.

I want to show that $T$ is well-defined.

I have shown that the value of $Tx$ does not depend on the choice of $x_n$.

Do I have to show that the limit actually exist? And how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\{T_0 x_n \}$ is a Cauchy sequence, since

$$ \Vert T_0 x_n - T_0 x_m \Vert \leq \Vert T_0 \Vert \Vert x_n - x_m \Vert \to 0. $$

So, supposing $X$ is Banach, the limit exists.